# Flipping axes direction in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

**Version I**

Let's say I have a simple code like shown below:

```
data = Table[{i, i^2, i^3}, {i, -1, +1, 0.01}];
Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, Line@data}, Axes -> True, ViewPoint -> {-2, 2, 1}, ViewVertical -> {0, 2, 0}]
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Is there a more-less elegant way **to reverse the direction of one of the axes?** I.e. to make so that values on one of the axes run from higher values to lower. Please note that I am not talking about some sort of rotation. I am aiming to flip the axis **without changing the active view**.

In a 2d `ListPlot`case it is as easy as utilizing `ScalingFunctions->{"Reverse", None}`. Sadly `ScalingFunctions` do not work in this case.

**Version II**

I provide another example concerning the question here. So, a data to be plotted can be found by the [link](https://kth.box.com/s/ugj2j8eq5ye0g0if54a7y7mul0scsi5m). And here is the code I used to plot it:

```
data = Import["data.hdf", {"Datasets", "Dataset1"}];
exp = Graphics3D[{Line /@ data}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7.5}, All, All}, 
Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
ImageSize -> 600, 
ViewPoint -> {1.4, -2.6, 0.5}, ViewVertical -> {0.3, -0.5, 1.6}]
```

As a result I get following output:

[image: Output 1]

In this particular cases I want to flip the x axis, so I apply the two step transformations suggested in answer:

```
exp /. Graphics3D[a_, o__] :> Graphics3D[
a, 
Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"], Automatic, Automatic},
o]
```

This is what I get as a preliminary output of this step:

[image]

Then I continue with step 2:

```
exp /. Graphics3D[a_, o__] :> Graphics3D[
GeometricTransformation[a, ScalingTransform[{-1, 1, 1}]],
Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"], Automatic, Automatic}, 
o]
```

And here is the final output:

[image]

So, sadly suggested solutions fails in my case or perhaps (most probably) I am applying it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation) with a non-default [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks) specification. I will do it in 2 steps. First, reverse one of the ticks:

```
g /. Graphics3D[a_,o__] :> Graphics3D[
    a,
    Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"],Automatic,Automatic},
    o
]
```

[image]

Then, use [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation) to invert the corresponding graphics primitives:

```
g /. Graphics3D[a_,o__] :> Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[a, ScalingTransform[{1, 1, -1}]],
    Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"],Automatic,Automatic},
    o
]
```

[image]

**Comment**

The OP commented that my code only works for symmetric axes, so here is an example with asymmetric axes using the same technique:

```
data = Table[{i,6i^2,i^3},{i,-1,+1,0.01}];
g = Graphics3D[
    {Red,Thick,Line@data},
    Axes->True,
    ViewPoint->{-2,2,1},
    ViewVertical->{0,2,0}
]
```

[image]

And my answer applied to the middle coordinate:

```
g /. Graphics3D[a_,o__] :> Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[a,ScalingTransform[{1,-1,1}]],
    Ticks->{Automatic,Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"],Automatic},
    o
]
```

[image]

It looks like my answer works with asymmetric axes as well.

**Comment 2**

If the original graphic has an explicit [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange), then you need to include an appropriately transformed [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange). For the OP example, the following does this:

```
exp /. Graphics3D[a_,o___] :> Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[a,ScalingTransform[{-1,1,1}]],
    Ticks->{Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"],Automatic,Automatic},
    PlotRange->{{0,-7.5},All,All},
    o
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it seem to be working only with symmetrical axes. So, in my case, the axis I am trying to make run in a reverse direction is a Y axis with values going from 0 to 6. This code doesn't really reverse it, instead it only multiplies all of the values by "-1". So new axis becomes negative.

Comment: @BulatMunavirov I added an example with asymmetric axes, and I don't see the behavior you describe. Perhaps you can update your question with the graphic that has the issue you describe.

Comment: I have modified the question adding the original data and code I am dealing with. Please see modifications under "Version II" part.

Comment: @BulatMunavirov See update